# TypeORM, need to add "WHERE IN (...)" in query condition & only when there is a value for it

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

I am using TypeORM (version 0.2.40) in my node.js project written in TypeScript .  I know to find a record from database I can do :

```
userRepository.find({ where: { firstName: "John", company: "foo" } });
```

It executes query:

```
SELECT * FROM "user"
WHERE "firstName" = 'John' AND "company" = 'foo'
```

Now I have an array in typescript which might hold or might not hold integer values:

```
 const userIds = params.user_ids; // e.g. undefined or [1,2,3]
```

I would like my query to add `WHERE userIds IN (1,2,3)` if `userIds` contains such values otherwise don't add this where condition.

I tried (In this case `params` might contain a `company` or might not contain too):

```
const {params} = parseRequest();

query: SelectQueryBuilder<MyEntity> = ...;

query.where({
  firstName: 'John',
  ...(params.company && { company: params.company }), // add 'company' condition only if value exists
}).andWhere({/* how to do here have 'WHERE IN (1,2,3)' if value exist?*/});
```

I have two questions:

1. How to only add the "WHERE IN (...)" only if  `params.user_ids` exist (same as for `params.company`)?  (Please feel free to remove my `andWhere` usage if there is a neat way)
2. What is the syntax of TypeORM to add the "WHERE IN (...)" logic for `params.user_ids` assuming value exists?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, don't forget to give it a upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple conditional along with the `IN` operator.
E.g.

```js
import {In} from "typeorm";

let query = ...
if (userIds?.length) {
  // WHERE IN [...userIds]
  query = query.where({userId: In([...userIds])})
}
// Continue chaining.
query = ...
```

Resources:

- [Conditional](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3103)
- [In](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1239)
- [Docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options)

Comment: `query.getSql()` shows me it doesn't yield `WHERE IN` but `WHERE "MyEntity"."userId" = $1`

Comment: @user842225 try it now. Added the In operator and the relevant sources.